# How to use latest SASS version in Angular?

Tags: angular, sass

I have an Angular 2+ project and i want to use the latest SASS functions.
How i can do that?

I've made some research and i know that is possible with `schematics` in the `angular.json` file.

Here is an example:

```
"schematics": {
    ...
  }
```

In my `package.json` i don't have the SASS package so i can't update the single package with **npm**.

How i can use latest SASS editing the Angular configuration?

Comment: The SASS compiler is provided in the CLI. Simply update the CLI to get the latest SASS version.

Comment: @Maryannah i want update only SASS and not the CLI.

Comment: Then update your global package `node-sass` (not sure it will work though)

Comment: @Maryannah i don't have `node-sass` in my *package.json*. Why i need to update it if i don't have?

Comment: *The SASS compiler is provided in the CLI*. The Angular CLI is installed globally (through `npm i -g`). It's not a dependency of your project, because you simply do not need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just `npm i node-sass@latest` or for globally install to CLI 
`npm i -g node-sass@latest`

I hope it helps!

Comment: I get the following warning after doing this: `'node-sass' usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version. To opt-out of the deprecated behaviour and start using 'sass' uninstall 'node-sass'.`